# API Routes Can't Find MongoDB Database

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

Okay, so I am having an issue with Routing I believe. I have a MongoDB database created and running, my Express/Node server is connected to it. The actual DB connection is separate from the main Server.js file.

I have a api.js file that houses all of my APIs.

```js
// Added code below
var Todo = require('../models/todo.js');

module.exports = function(app){
 
 // API Routes
  // Get all todos
  app.get('/api/todos', function(req, res) {
   Todo.find(function(err, todos) {
    if(err) {
     res.send(err);
    }
    res.json(todos);
   });
  });

  // Create todos
  app.post('/api/todos', function(req, res) {
   Todo.create({
    text: req.body.text,
    priority: req.body.priority,
    done: false
   }, function(err, todo) {
    if(err) {
     res.send(err);
    }
    Todo.find(function(err, todos) {
     if(err) {
      res.send(err);
     }
     res.json(todos);
    });
   });
  });

  // Delete todos
  app.delete('/api/todos/:todo_id', function(req, res) {
   Todo.remove({
    _id : req.params.todo_id
   }, function(err, todo) {
    if(err) {
     res.send(err);
    }
    Todo.find(function(err, todos) {
     if(err) {
      res.send(err);
     }
     res.json(todos);
    });
   });
  });
 
};
```

Now, in my main Server.js file I use that API like this...

```js
//Just added this line below
var todo = require('./app/models/todos.js');
require('./app/routes/api.js')(app);
```

This is what my Schema build file is looking like...

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


var Todo = mongoose.model('Todo', {
 text: String,
 priority: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Todo', Todo);
```

So, the error I am receiving when trying the access (localhost:3000/api/todos) is that the Todo (Database) is undefined.

Am I forgetting something here?

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: Is there anywhere in the `app.js` file where you require the todos like so: `var Todo = require('../path-to-todos/Todo');`? If not this is what might be causing the issue

Comment: Thanks for responding quickly, Vasil. I did not have that and after adding it I got the "cannot GET /api/todos"

Comment: could you update the code sample?

Comment: So in the Server.js above I added that new line of code.

Comment: I meant you should add this file in the `api.js` file as currently Todo is undefined in the context of the api module. Rework it look like so:

`var Todo = require('../path/todos');

module.exports = ...`

Comment: the server.js is my app.js, it is the main node file.

Comment: I meant `api.js` as currently there Todo is undefined

Comment: Does your create resource work?

Comment: Yes, Oliver. It did before I started splitting everything up into its own folders. I'm just a little foggy on the routing department. =)

Comment: Vasil, I have updated the api.js file to include the require. Do I need it in the main server.js file?

Comment: Then please try `Todo.find({}, function(err, todos) { ... });`

Comment: I still have the "cannot GET /api/todos" in the browser.

Comment: Did you forget to connect to your DB? `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');` right after the require of mongoose